# No resource found that matches the given name - Error while using CollapsingToolBar

Tags: android, imageview, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm new to Android and using a CollapsingToolBar. When I set the image in toolbar, it gives me the below error. I was getting an error which says "Cruncher cruncher error" but resolved it by creating different for mdpi and hdpi but then this error occurred.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name (at \u0027src\u0027 with value \u0027@mipmap/wintertiger\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"E:\\Android\\Ewaid\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_edit_user_profile.xml","position":{"startLine":36,"startColumn":29,"startOffset":1597,"endColumn":48,"endOffset":1616}}],"original":""}
```

My layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolBar"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="fdgfhhg"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/wintertiger"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:id="@+id/userImage"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

My resource is mipmap/wintertiger.png

Any help will be appreciated.

My console for full logs:

```
           Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

        Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
        :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
        :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
        :app:checkDebugManifest
        :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
        :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
        :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2300Library UP-TO-DATE
        :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
        :app:prepareDebugDependencies
        :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
        :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
        :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
        :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
        :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
        :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
        :app:mergeDebugResources
        AAPT out(1086801821) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
        AAPT out(1772881340) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
        AAPT out(1623148880) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
        AAPT out(256342006) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
        AAPT out(256342006) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
        AAPT out(1086801821) : No Delegate set : lost message:Done
        AAPT err(1772881340): libpng error: Not a PNG file
        AAPT err(1086801821): libpng error: Not a PNG file
        AAPT err(1086801821): libpng error: Not a PNG file
        AAPT err(256342006): libpng error: Not a PNG file
        AAPT err(256342006): libpng error: Not a PNG file
        AAPT err(1623148880): libpng error: Not a PNG file

        :app:processDebugManifest
        :app:processDebugResources
        AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name (at \u0027src\u0027 with value \u0027@mipmap/wintertiger\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"E:\\Android\\Ewaid\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\activity_edit_user_profile.xml","position":{"startLine":36,"startColumn":29,"startOffset":1597,"endColumn":48,"endOffset":1616}}],"original":""}


     FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\pegasus\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.483 secs
```

Comment: Are you sure your drawables are pngs?

Comment: @ChrisThoma Yes.. I made sure by deleting the resource and including the resource again

Comment: Same here with AAPT 23.0.1 (Windows 10): AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name (at \u0027icon\u0027 with value \u0027@drawable/ic_launcher\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AndroidMobilePushApp\\app\\build\\intermediates\\manifests\\full\\debug\\AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":28,"startColumn":22,"startOffset":1647,"endColumn":43,"endOffset":1668}}],"original":""}

Comment: @Thorsten I was able to resolve the issue by changing the image resource. I deleted my old resources and used a new one. If you save a jpg image with .png extension, it won't work.